# как записать значения переменной list в файл?

Tags: python

как записать список:

```
a = ['купить слона', 'купить синего слона', 'цены на слонов']
```

в txt файл в следующем виде:

```
купить слона
купить синего слона
цены на слонов
```

Comment: `open('file.txt', 'w+').write('\n'.join(a))`

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open('xyz.txt','w')  # открытие в режиме записи
f.write('Hello \n World')  # запись Hello World в файл
Hello #вывод содержимого
World #вывод содержимого
f.close()  # закрытие файла
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
    for i in alist:
          f.write(i)
```

Если нужно просто добавить в конец - режим 'а', если нужно в пустой записать, то 'w'

Answer (score 0):

```
In [5]: a = ['купить слона', 'купить синего слона', 'цены на слонов']

In [6]: with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
   ...:     f.write("\n".join(a))

~ cat file.txt
купить слона
купить синего слона
цены на слонов
```